# Survival Analysis_Seaweed Life Stages

Tags: survival

I have a data set for observations of life stages of red seaweed with the surface area (mm2) taken on day 1 - 8, 10 and 14 (n = 10).  Each life stage has been assigned a number 1 - 5 for a life stage and 8 for death.

Culture vessel - petri dish had 10 identified and then tracked. 2D surface area measured and life stage noted.
Factors:
Treatment - 3 different nutrients
Intensity - 6 different light intensities
Time - Days 1 to 8, 10 and 14.

What I want to find out via a survival analysis is
Time to different stages (germination/holdfast/branching/death)
Time to different stages under the treatment
Time to different stages under the intensity
Time to different stages under treatment x intensity

Currently using R and getting Time error coding etc too. Have Time entered as 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10 and 14.  Should this be the actual date or what format?

Also should I be considering censoring interval and/or truncate.

Thanks in advance, I’ve been told it’s a challenge this one.
But very much needed results.
Cheers

Comment: # create a Surv object
survobj <- with(S1, Surv(as.numeric(Time,Stage)))
# plot survival distribution of the total sample
# Kaplan-meier estimator
fit0 <-survfit(survobj~1, data = S1)
summary(fit0)                
plot(fit0, xlab="Time in Days", ylab="% Surviving", yscale=100, main = "Survival Distribution (Overall)")